# Select query to get the DDL of the stored procedure ,Tables in snowflake

Tags: database, snowflake-schema

Do we have a select query to get the DDL for the SP and Tables displayed in Snowfalke

In SQL we have something like Sphelptext.

Regards
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there is the [GET_DDL function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl)